# Extract XML out of xml.gz file with PHP

Tags: php

I want to use the opendata from the dutch website opendata.ndw.nu in PHP.

But they are using .xml.gz files for some of them, and i'm a bit stuck in how to open these files and show them in XML.

I've tried the following:

```
<?php
$content = file_get_contents("http://opendata.ndw.nu/brugopeningen.xml.gz");
$uncompressed = gzdecode($content);
$string = simplexml_load_string($uncompressed);
print_r($string);
?>
```

But the output I get is empty as shown below:

> SimpleXMLElement Object ( )

When I print the variable $uncompressed I get the following:

https://prnt.sc/4drjYA-y8T_D

I've googled a lot but I can't seem to find any soloution. Can I get a push in the right direction?

Comment: That code is working just fine. What are you trying to do? What do you mean by "show them in XML"?

Comment: @Sammitch sorry for my late reply, I am trying to get the data from that file and print it onto my website. When I run this code Í'm getting this reply: "SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) "